# extract widget to the Gridview.builder - flutter

Tags: flutter, gridview, widget

I have my GridView.Builder that show 5 cardViews categories on my homepage.
I already implemented the `onTap` method, and everything works fine, a part that on the `child` of gridView im not able to call the model class.
I find it hard to implement the model class widget in order to get a custom name and icon for each card.

**Here my homepage**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
      title: Text('Pocket Chef'),
      centerTitle: true,
    ),
    body: GridView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      gridDelegate:
      SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
      itemCount: DUMMY_CATEGORIES
          .map((categoryItem) =>
          CategoryItems(categoryItem.name, categoryItem.icon))
          .toList()
          .length,
      itemBuilder: (_, index) {
        return InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            if (index == 0) {
              Navigator.of(context).push(
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Screen1()));
            } else if (index == 1) {
              Navigator.of(context).push(
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Screen2()));
            }
            else if (index == 2) {
              Navigator.of(context).push(
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Screen3()));
            
          },
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Icon(Icons.add, size: 60,),
              Text('name'),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    )
```

Right now i just add `Column` with icon.add and text 'name', because if i try to pass the `CategoryItem.icon`, i get error.

**My CategoryItem class**

```
 class CategoryItems extends StatelessWidget {
 final String name;
 final IconData icon;

CategoryItems(this.name, this.icon);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Card(
  elevation: 10.0,
  child: InkWell(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Icon(icon, size: 60,),
        Text(name),
      ],
      ),
     ),
   );
  }
}
```

**And here my list**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_projects/models/category.dart';

const DUMMY_CATEGORIES = const [
Category(
  name: "Calcolo W", id: "1", icon: Icons.food_bank),
Category(
  name: "Farina", id: "2", icon: Icons.food_bank ),
Category(
  name: "Alcol", id: "3", icon: Icons.food_bank),
Category(
  name: "Panna", id: "4", icon: Icons.food_bank),
Category(
  name: "Cioccolato", id: "5", icon: Icons.face)
```

];

[image: this is what i get]

[image: This is what i am looking for]

Comment: Could you please provide the code of the whole CategoryItem class?

Comment: Sure. Now the CategoryItem class it's complete,  i added also the list of item

Comment: What error are you getting from the icon?

Comment: I want to open a new page screen, if it is what you meant. However the output right now it is 5 cards with the "add" icon and the text "name"

Comment: if i add the string " children: <Widget> [   Icon(icon, size: 60,),   Text(name)" i get error: Undefined  name 'icon',  Undefined  name 'name'. I was trying to pass the icon and name from CategoryItem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a list of categories as 'DUMMY_CATEGORIES'. So just use icon:Icon(DUMMY_CATEGORIES[index].icon) and Text(DUMMY_CATEGORIES[index].name)

for your help here is the code:

```
    body: GridView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      .....
      itemCount: DUMMY_CATEGORIES.length,
      itemBuilder: (_, index) {
        return InkWell(
          onTap: () {
           ....
          },
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Icon(
                DUMMY_CATEGORIES[index].icon,
                size: 60,
              ),
              Text(DUMMY_CATEGORIES[index].name),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
```

> Make sure you created a list of DUMMY_CATEGORIES as follows:

```
 List<Category> DUMMY_CATEGORIES = [
       Category(name: "Calcolo W", id: "1", icon: Icons.food_bank),
       Category(name: "Farina", id: "2", icon: Icons.food_bank),
       Category(name: "Alcol", id: "3", icon: Icons.food_bank),
       Category(name: "Panna", id: "4", icon: Icons.food_bank),
       Category(name: "Cioccolato", id: "5", icon: Icons.face)
 ];
```